# NodeJS: Make it possible for user input when running child_process

Tags: node.js, bash, maven, process

I'm trying to create a Node script that will ask the user a few questions, save the input and using the answers run a `mvn archetype:generate` command to install their environment.

I got as far to where I get the Maven command running. But when Maven asks for user input for values such as `groupId` and `` I can enter the values, give an `[enter]` and that's where it stops.

It doesn't take input and process them. All it does is display it, as the CLI does, but doesn't accept them.

Here's a snippet of code with the values for user input pre-filled:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var answerCollection = {
  "name": "nameOfMyArchetype", //answer of inquiry
  "version": "1.2.3.4" //answer of inquiry
};
var cmd = "mvn";
var args = [
  "archetype:generate",
  "-DarchetypeArtifactId=" + answerCollection.name,
  "-DarchetypeGroupId=com.backbase.expert.tools",
  "-DarchetypeVersion=" + answerCollection.version
];
var runCmd = function(cmd, args, callback) {

  var child = spawn(cmd, args);

  child.stdin.pipe(process.stdin);
  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

  child.stdout.on('end', function(res) {
    console.log("stdout:end");
    callback(res);
  });

  child.stderr.on('data', function(text) {
    console.log("stderr:data");
    console.log(data);
  });

  child.stderr.on('exit', function(data) {
    console.log("stderr:exit");
    console.log(data);
  });

};
```

So far I've tried the above code with `child_process` and `spawn = require('child_process').spawn('bash')`.

**Question**: Is there any other way to make sure I can trigger a script and if that returns with a prompt and asks for input I can type and enter and the script will continue?

Answer (score 1):

From Facebook I got this tip to use [`cross-spawn`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn), instead of [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

From [Robert Haritonov](https://github.com/operatino):

> Use cross-spawn: `spawn('bower', bowerCommand, {stdio:'inherit'}).on('close', function () {});`

This works perfectly well and provides exactly the behaviour I need.